# ssh-add returns "Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory" even though agent is running

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-agent

Windows 10 20H2, build 19042.685

I'm trying to use the SSH agent in the built-in OpenSSH client on Windows 10. The agent is running:

```
C:\Users\Daniel> Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -like '*ssh-agent*'}

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

However, `ssh-add` is still throwing the same error:

```
C:\Users\Daniel> ssh-add C:\Users\Daniel\.ssh\id_ed25519
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, seems to have started after I moved the Windows TEMP folder from C: to D: (using Windows10's correct ways of doing this) in a folder with a space in the name. Everything works, all apps, except for ssh-agent which now appears to be completely broken - I suspect some obvious bug in ssh on windows.

Answer (score 2):

I found that something in Windows10 is setting the path to ssh-agent as an env-var, but cannot cope with spaces in foldernames. Someone forgot to escape their inputs! (AAAAAAAARRRRGGGGH!).

To test: (in git-bash, which I'm currently using)

```
echo "$(ssh-agent)"
```

...gives what your env has setup (in my case: stupidly) for how it will find/access ssh-agent. I got:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/d/Windows10 Temporary Files/ssh-XXXXXXX/agent.YYYYY; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=54456; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 54456;
```

...oh look! Someone forgot that folders can have spaces, and didn't bother to escape their inputs (the first line is corrupt, it includes the "export" command).

Re-exporting that env-variable correctly (wrap the "/d/...YYYY" with single quotes, remove the trailing ";", and remove the "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;" part) causes ssh-agent to work properly again.